# Up to date elementary OS is incredibly slow, whats wrong?

Tags: system, graphic-drivers, nvidia

My system is:

- Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i5-6600K CPU @ 3.50GHz
- NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] (rev a1)
- 16.4 GB memory
- 233.7 GB storage

I'm using the latest `nvidia-driver-415` driver from [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter), yet I can't even run `vlc` 720p without it lagging.

I was having zero issues less then a day ago on my system. I can't imagine anything changed.

I just watch YouTube videos and build websites on my PC, everything I install is through a Vagrant VirtualBox

So no modifications to the base system...

Any help?

---

Update.

Ran system for 30 minutes
Restart system

ran system again for 30 minutes

Restart again

on the 4th attempt.
System is working correctly again

Maybe my ssd is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest that this might be an SSD failing.
My laptop was going slow, locking up taking 2 or 3 goes to boot.
I found out my SSD was failing, replaced it with a new one and all is great.
Ps my SSD was 2 weeks old.